# Searching for both word and its negation in a string using java regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to find both word and its negation in a string using java. For example, say

```
String str = "The product contains no sodium but contains potassium"
```

I am searching for both "sodium" and "no sodium" in this string. I would like to make specific actions based on the outcome. However, how can I make sure that once "no sodium" is identified in this string, sodium does not get matcher using regex. I have a list of such words(substrings) that I need to search for in a large set of strings.

For now, I am using an arraylist to store the words and strings to be matched using which I am making a pattern which is used to search in the input string

```
String patternString = "\\b(" + StringUtils.join(wordsSearch,"|") + ")\\b"; //making a pattern to search
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
//using matcher to find the substrings that I have mentioned earlier
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
```

Comment: I think it will depend on what you consider to be 'negation'. For the specific example, `\\b((?:no )?sodium)\\b` would do what you want, as would `\\b(no sodium|sodium)\\b` or `\\b(sodium|no sodium)\\b`. So what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Negation in the sense that product does contain sodium or does not contain sodium. In such a case, given a product description, I need to identify if the description contains sodium or phrases like does not contain sodium or no sodium etc @Jerry

Comment: If you have not done it yet, have a look at [Greedy, Reluctant, and Possessive Quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) section of the Java RegEx tutorial.  It seems to have some relevance to your task at hand.

Comment: @Lazyprogrammer But that just made the question suddently broader. What about `absence of sodium`? And the other many ways of indicating "no sodium"?

Comment: For readability, you should do this in two steps.  Search for "no sodium" first.  If there's no match, then search for "sodium".  Also, be careful about word breaks - you don't want the presence of "amino acids" to register a hit for "no acid".

Comment: Yes, but for now could you suggest any solution for identifying negation phrase like "no sodium" or "no calories" over phrases like "sodium" or "calories" (they should not simultaneously match in a string). Eventually, I would like to scale the solution to include the other kinds of phrases possible. @Jerry

Comment: OK, how do we deal with "rennet free cheese"?

Comment: For now, I would like to identify it as containing cheese as "no cheese" does not match but "cheese" does @DavidWallace

Comment: I still say you should do it in two passes.  Remember, you (or someone else) will have to make sense of this code in 6 months' time.

Comment: Maybe a little off-topic, but wouldn't be better to use Apache Lucene to search/discard given text-phrases instead of creating a similar functionality from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matcher won't find overlapping matches, so for your example this will already do what you want it to.  However you could get into some issues if you have multiple strings that have a common prefix, for example "sodium" and "sodium chloride".

To make sure you always get the longest match, make sure that you always have longer strings first within the alternation.  So as long as your regex was something like `\b(sodium chloride|sodium)\b` the regex engine will first try `sodium chloride` and then fall back to `sodium` if necessary.

In this case you should sort `wordsSearch` by string length (longest at front) before creating the regex.

Comment: Yeah I had just realized that, made an edit which adds some additional explanation.  I think the answer still makes sense for what OP is trying to do.

Comment: but still just the word "sodium" will be identified in the String right as such a word exists delimited by word boundary? Please correct me if I am wrong. @F.J

Comment: In general, regular expression libraries will not find overlapping matches.  When one match is found the matcher will start looking for the next match just after the previous match, so when "no sodium" is matched the matcher will try to find the next match after the "m", so you wouldn't get "sodium" as a separate match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match only the `no sodium` then its as usual.

But if you want to match only `sodium` not having `no` before, then it will be

```
(?<!no) sodium
```